# Insertar input en pd.query

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito si podrán ayudarme en lo siguiente. Soy muy nuevo en programación y estoy haciendo un "programa" para el trabajo en el que el usuario ingresa dos fechas y yo debo etiquetar a los registros que se encuentran por fuera de esas dos fechas. Los valores que ingresa el usuario fueron convertidos a fecha mediante `datetime.strptime`, y la columna con la que se compara fueron convertidas a fecha mediante `pd.to_datetime`. El código de error que me tira es:

```
SyntaxError: Python keyword not valid identifier in numexpr query
```

De acuerdo a lo que pude investigar, el mismo es por que existe un espacio en el valor que uso para comparar (el input) que vendría dado por la separación de los minutos horas y segundos con la fecha de `día/mes/año`. No entiendo el motivo de por que me lo pone así.

DATA PARA COMPARAR (COLUMNA PROXIMO VTO):

```
    Proximo_Vto FecUltCuotaImpaga
0   2022-11-02  2021-11-01
1   2022-11-02  2022-11-01
2   2022-11-02  2021-11-04
3   2022-11-02  2021-11-08
4   2022-11-02  2021-11-01
... ... ...
157031  2019-07-10  2019-07-08
157032  2019-07-10  2019-07-08
157033  2021-08-04  2020-08-09
157034  2020-06-30  2020-04-30
157035  2021-04-04  2020-04-05
```

```
   # Creamos el botón para consultar si se envían vigentes:
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def obtener_info():
    respuesta= lista_desplegable.get()
    if respuesta == "SI":
        print("INGRESE LA FECHA DE INICIO DE CICLO (dd/mm/aaaa):")
        fecha_inicio= datetime.strptime(input(), '%d/%m/%Y')
        print("INGRESE LA FECHA DE FIN DE CICLO(dd/mm/aaaa):")
        fecha_fin= datetime.strptime(input(), '%d/%m/%Y')
        print(f"el ciclo comienza el {fecha_inicio} y termina 
{fecha_fin}")
    
         # AQUÍ DEBAJO ESTÁ EL CÓDIGO QUE DEBE USARSE PARA AGREGAR A 
LOS VIGENTES (uso la fecha de próximo vto.):
        fuera_ciclo= df_cartera.query(f"(Proximo_Vto < {fecha_inicio} 
| Proximo_Vto > {fecha_fin}) & Estado == 'VIGENTE' & BASE.isnull()")                                       
        df_cartera.loc[fuera_ciclo.index, "BASE"]= "V_FUERA_CICLO"
    
    
    

   else:
       print("VIGENTES EXCLUIDOS")
    

ventana= Tk()
ventana.title("VIGENTES")
ventana.geometry("500x300")

#LISTA DESPLEGABLE
lista_desplegable= ttk.Combobox(ventana, width= 17)
lista_desplegable.place(x=50,y=100)

#LISTA DE OPCIONES
opciones= ["SI", "NO"]

#INSERTAR VALORES
lista_desplegable["values"]= opciones

# botón
Button(ventana, text= "¿Desea agregar vigentes?", 
command=obtener_info).place(x=200,y=100)

ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor pon el código como texto

Comment: Hecho Christian, gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón del espacio que te aparece es que la variable `fecha_inicio` no es ya una cadena, sino un objeto de tipo `datetime` debido a que lo has convertido en uno. Este tipo de objetos contienen no sólo una fecha, sino también una hora (por defecto 00:00) y tienen sus propias reglas para convertirse en string. Según esas reglas se imprimirá la fecha seguida de la hora separadas por un espacio. Esa regla se aplica como parte de la f-string, donde aparezca por ejemplo `f"{fecha_inicio}"`.

Esos espacios causan que la expresión no pueda ser comprendida por `query()`. La solución más simple quizás sea no convertir el input a `datetime` sino dejarlo como cadena. A fin de cuentas, lo que vas a insertar en la `.query()` también será una cadena, por lo que no encuentro mucho sentido en convertir la entrada del usuario a `datetime` para después volver a convertirla en cadena. Para eso mejor dejarla como estaba.

No obstante, si por la razón que sea la necesitas como `datetime`, entonces puedes extraer sólo la fecha (y así ya no aparecerá la hora) con la expresión `"{fecha_inicio.date()}` dentro de la f-string.

**Importante**. Al margen de lo anterior, tienes otro problema en la expresión que le estás pasando a la `query()`, pues hay varias operaciones booleanas combinadas.  En este caso tienes que poner entre paréntesis cada una de las condiciones, porque los operadores `&` y `|` tienen menos precedencia que `>`, `<`, `==`, etc en esas expresiones. Es decir esto está mal: `"a > 0 & b <0"` y debe ponerse así `"(a>0) & (b<0)"`.

Es decir, en tu caso la expresión correcta sería

```
f"((Proximo_Vto < {fecha_inicio}) | (Proximo_Vto > {fecha_fin})) & (Estado == 'VIGENTE') & (BASE.isnull())"
```

### Actualización

No tengo claro que `.query()` pueda "comprender" que algo como `25/12/2021` sea una fecha, y supongo que más bien lo entenderá como una división. Podría quizás arreglarse poniendo cada una de esas fechas entre comillas, así:

```
f"((Proximo_Vto < '{fecha_inicio}') | (Proximo_Vto > '{fecha_fin}')) & (Estado == 'VIGENTE') & (BASE.isnull())"
```

pero en ese caso no sé yo si el comparador `<` será lo bastante "inteligente" como para detectar que la cadena "25/12/2021" deba compararse como fecha y no alfabéticamente como cadena.

Creo que todos estos problemas se resuelven si no usas `.query()`, que te obliga a codificar la consulta como una cadena con los inconvenientes que esto tiene y que estamos descubriendo, sino que uses `.loc[]` que, aunque obliga a escribir una expresión algo más larga, al menos es una expresión python y no una cadena, por lo que creo que no tendrá estos inconvenientes.

Sería entonces así:

```py
d = df_cartera # Le pongo un nombre más corto para escribir menos
fuera_ciclo= d.loc[
                ( (d.Proximo_Vto < fecha_inicio) |
                  (d.Proximo_Vto > fecha_fin) )
                & (d.Estado == "VIGENTE")
                & (d.BASE.isnull())
              ]
```

Para que las comparaciones con `fecha_inicio` y `fecha_fin` funcionen bien, éstas deben ser de tipo `datetime` (ahora sí), pero también tiene que ser de tipo `datetime` la columna "Proximo_Vto" del dataframe. Si no lo es, tienes que usar `pandas.to_datetime()` para convertirla.

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Hice la modificación que me dijiste, y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, por alguna razón me separa el texto con espacios por más que lo ponga todo junto. 

File "<unknown>", line 1
    ((Proximo_Vto <25 /12 /2021 )or (Proximo_Vto >25 /0 1 /2022 ))and (Estado =='VIGENTE')and (BASE .isnull ())
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Yo lo había convertido a datetime por que pensé que era necesario hacerlo para compararlo con los valores de la columna que están en ese formato.

Comment: Posiblemente se deba a que está considerando 25/12/2021 como una división. He añadido una ampliación a la respuesta con otro enfoque que creo que causará menos problemas

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! de verdad me ha sido de gran ayuda!!